# Merge two json together into one json in ngOnInit function

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have an Angular component that on loading call 2 service methods and those methods in return, return the data back in json format. I want to merge those two jsons together. I did looked at some other threads and found that `Object.assign` can be used for this purpose but the problem is that i am adding data to objects inside the subscriber function and `Object.assign` is outside the subscriber function so objects are undefined outside the subscriber function. Here is my code

```
export class UpcomingClassesComponent implements OnInit {

  times: ClassTimes = new ClassTimes();
  schedule: ClassSchedule = new ClassSchedule();
    classes: any; 
    timing: any;
    data: any;

  constructor(private router:Router,
              private _classService: ClassServiceProxy) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._classService.GetClassData()
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
      this.schedule = result;
      this.classes = this.schedule;
      //console.log(this.classes);
    })

    this._classService.GetClassTimes()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.times = data;
      this.timing = this.times;
      //console.log(this.timing);
    })

    let completeData = Object.assign({}, this.classes, this.timing);
    console.log(completeData); 

    }
```

`CompleteData` is returning me an object in console and nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Promise

```
ngOnInit() {
  let dataPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    this._classService.GetClassData()
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
      resolve(result[0]);
    })
  });

  let timesPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    this._classService.GetClassTimes()
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
      resolve(result[0]);
    })
  });

  Promise.all([dataPromise, timesPromise])
  .then((values) => {
    console.log(values);
    let completeData = { ...values[0], ...values[1]};
    // let completeData = Object.assign({}, values[0], values[1]);
    console.log("final results : ", completeData); 
  });
}
```

Comment: returned me  `0:null, 1:null`

Comment: @ahsannissar added two console log, please check if you are getting any data or not.

Comment: yup this code does show me `GetClassTimes` data and `GetClassData` but after your promise.all i again got  `0:null, 1:null`

Comment: @ahsannissar please try now

Comment: jay yes this did show me the output but again both json are in two differnet objects i.e 0 and 1 while i want the two jsons in one json.

Comment: @ahsannissar this will make one JSON from two `let completeData = { ...values[0], ...values[1]}; ` i have added console log with `final results`

Comment: it hurts me saying this jay but i think you also ran into the same problem which is being faced by @Ramesh in another answer on this thread

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199760/discussion-between-ahsan-nissar-and-jay-vaghasiya).

Comment: @ahsannissar I have added `Object.assign` this is final try, please try and let me know, if it works or not ?

Comment: @ahsannissar nice

Answer (score 2):

try forkJoin

```
 forkJoin([_classService.GetClassTimes(),_classService.GetClassTimes()
  ]).subscribe((result: any[]) => {

    this.schedule = result[0];
    this.classes = this.schedule;

    this.times = result[1];
    this.timing = this.times;

   let completeData = {...this.classes, ...this.timing];
   console.log(completeData);
  })
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2tyv93

Comment: how am i supposed to call this function from ngOnInit?what parameters do i need to pass?

Comment: @ahsannissar  same as you did in your question just replace your code with mine  and import { forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

Comment: nope bro this is showing me only `this.timing` data in the json but not `this.classes`. I think the subscriber that is executed later on is the one showing the data but the subscriber that executed earlier is not showing its data.

Comment: @ahsannissar I added stackblitz URL for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this._classService.GetClassTimes()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.times = data;
      this.timing = this.times;
      this._classService.GetClassData()
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
      this.schedule = result;
      this.classes = this.schedule;
      //console.log(this.classes);
})
      this.completeData();
      //console.log(this.timing);
    })

completeData() {
let completeData = { ...this.classes, ...this.timing};
    console.log(completeData);
}
```

Comment: nope not working its still returning me only times but not classes details.

Comment: are you able to see the logs of `this.classes` and `this.timing`

Comment: yes `this.classes` and `this.timing` does show there own data but in the completeData function it is only showing me `this.timing` data

Comment: still returned same only `this.times`

Comment: can you post the screenshot of result of the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199759/discussion-between-ahsan-nissar-and-ramesh).

Answer (score 0):

`ForkJoin` is a better approach but it is advised to not to use indexes in its subscription. A better approach would be to use `tap` where we Assign the Object as they resolve. This helps in not manually indexing the results and help maintain scalability.

```
forkJoin([
  classes.pipe(tap(res => {
    Object.assign(completeData, res)
  })),
  timing.pipe(tap(res => {
    Object.assign(completeData, res)
  }))
]).subscribe(_ => {
  //do your further login
  console.log(completeData)
})
```

Stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-with-tap