# How do you combine data from two http posts into one data object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to combine data from two different http posts into one object variable. I wish to run the combined results through ng-repeat to display a combined list on screen. Is there a way to do this in standard java script or do I have to bring in a library? I tried object.assign but received a null or undefined object error.

```
$http.post('Url1', {
  param: @scope.myParam
}).success(function (data) {
  $scope.myData1 = data;
});

$http.post('Url2', {
  param: @scope.myParam
}).success(function (data) {
  $scope.myData2 = data;
});

$scope.myData = Object.assign($scope.myData1, $scope.myData2);
```

Comment: Again use  Promise.all to wait both call to be finished and then merge the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two json together into one json in ngOnInit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038134/merge-two-json-together-into-one-json-in-ngoninit-function)

Comment: The `.success` method has been [removed from the AngularJS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$q.all`:

```
var promise1 = $http.post('Url1', {
  param: @scope.myParam
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.data;
});

var promise1 = $http.post('Url2', {
  param: @scope.myParam
}).then(function (response) {
  return response.data;
});

$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then([data1, data2] => {
  $scope.myData = {...data1, ...data2};  //combine object
  //OR
  $scope.myData = [...data1, ...data2];  //combine array
});
```

Beware that the ES6 promises returned by `Promise.all` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

The promises returned by `$q.all` are integrated with the AngularJS framework.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 2):

I assume your data is of object type so you can do it using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like

```js
var obj1={a:1};
var obj2={b:2};

var obj3={...obj1,...obj2}

console.log(obj3)
```

in your case `$scope.myData = {...$scope.myData1,... $scope.myData2};`

if your data is array than use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
$scope.myData = $scope.myData1.concat($scope.myData2)
```

Also don't forgot await for promise as specified in other ans

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then( (res) => {//perform your merge here}
```

Comment: The Promise.all with spread operator definitely works where I could not get Object.assign to give me combined results. However, there is another complication I have with the Promise.all that I previously did not think about. I will not always call both http posts. Based on conditions, sometimes I will call one or the other or both. Can I just setup mutiple Promis.all's? For example: Promise.all([promise1, promise2]) ...., Promise.all([promise1])...., Promise.all([promise2]).....

Comment: @Bill yes you can

Answer (score 2):

Use Promise.all for both call to be finished:

```
var promise1 = $http.post('Url1', {
      param: @scope.myParam
    }).success(function (data) {
      $scope.myData1 = data;
    });

     var promise2 = $http.post('Url2', {
      param: @scope.myParam
    }).success(function (data) {
      $scope.myData2 = data;
    });

    Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then( (res) => {
        $scope.myData = Object.assign({}, $scope.myData1 , $scope.myData2 );
    });
```

Comment: NO errors this time but I'm not able to get that to work. $scope.myData1 has data. $scope.myData2 has data. $scope.myData has nothing.  Typescript is also involved. I'm guessing I have to declare promise1 &  promise2 in typescript. If so, what type of ojbects would they be?

Comment: @Bill i think you are not returning the data in both promise. So use this one : `$scope.myData = Object.assign({}, $scope.myData1, $scope.myData2);` i edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

URL calls are asynchronous, meaning they will run separately from the function. Having the Object assign after both calls means it will occur after the URLS calls are made, but NOT NECESSARILY after the calls finish, so both data values will be undefined. As suggested, it will be necessary to wait for both calls to finish before there will be data to combine together and use in other functions